# Dynamic Cell creation issue for fixed width Div using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have fixed width square div of dimension say 320X320 (as i want it to work in mobile as well). My criteria is like on first stage it will be one square and second stage it will divided into equal 4 squares like a grid of 320X320 with 4 parts and in third stage 9 squares grid and finally in fourth stage with 12 square grid.

This 320X320 can be variable my only criteria is like it should be compatible in mobile.

I will be using jQuery to draw square boxes based on each stage based on these calculations.

```
Stage 1: 320X320 [1 square]
Stage 2: 160.66X160.66 [4 squares] => 2 rows 2 columns
Stage 3: ?? [9 squares] => 3 rows 3 columns
Stage 4: ?? [12 squares] =>4 rows 3 columns
```

I go this far but i would like to get good suggestions apart from this as i don't like these fractions in pixels. I am not that good in Math :) so please excuse if above calculation is wrong.

Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maybe use something like this?

```html
<style>
    #container {
        display: table;
        height: 320px;
        width: 320px;
    }
    .row {
        display: table-row;
    }
    .square {
        border: 1px solid #00F;
        display: table-cell;
    }
</style>

<div id="container"></div>

<button onclick="makeSquares(1, 1)">one</button>
<button onclick="makeSquares(2, 2)">four</button>
<button onclick="makeSquares(3, 3)">nine</button>
<button onclick="makeSquares(4, 3)">twelve</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  function makeSquares(rows, columns) {
    var container = $('#container');
    container.find('.row').remove();
    for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
      var relement = $('<div class="row"></div>').appendTo(container);
      for (var column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
        relement.append('<div class="square">test</div>');
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I leave it as an exercise for the OP to understand what's going on here... :-p

Hope this helps!